# Finding a data source for demographics by zip code

Tags: datasource, demographics

does anyone know specific data sources that would provide demographics such as age or income by zip code? I was able to find specific regions like NYC or other locations but not all in one source. I checked the census data as well but was not successful in finding it there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late, but there is an API available with a lot of demographic-related data by ZIP code.  In case anyone else is looking:
https://rapidapi.com/aptitudeapps/api/zip-code-master/details

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).